I do not receive information from the template
My footer doesn’t use any view I need to get information to save it I used parcel rendering package to render but I don’t get any information to save it even if it’s a small tip I can find it
views code:
def footernews(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'includes/footer.html', {'myformmews': form})
        else:
            raise ValidationError('sorry infomations dont save...')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
        return render(request,'includes/footer.html',{'myformmews':form})

models code:
from django.db import models

class MassageNewsFoot(models.Model):

email=models.EmailField(max_length=32)
date=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'email: {self.email}---date: {self.date}'

forms code:
from django import forms
from home_app.models import MassageNewsFoot
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError



class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = MassageNewsFoot
        fields = '__all__'

        #style form footer in widget
        widgets ={
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control bordered bottom-only'
                                            ,'placeholder':'enter your email'}),
        }

urls code:
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'home_app'

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.Homepage.as_view(), name='home'),
    path("footer", views.footernews, name='footerrenderded'),

]

template code:


                <form action="" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="subscribe-form">
                        <div class="head">
                            news this site
                        </div>


                        <div class="input-wrap">

                            {{ myformmews.email }}

                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                                 <span class="outer-wrap">
                                  <span data-text="share">
                                   share
                                  </span>
                                 </span>
                            </button>


                        </div>
                </form>


And finally I gave it to template home:
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load render_partial %}
{% block content %}

html code ...

{% render_partial 'home_app:footerrenderded' %}
{% endblock %}

If you know how to render a template that is not rendered by any view and receive the data, I would be grateful if you could help me.
I wanted to receive the data so that I could save it, but I was sending information but not receiving it

In the last line you wrote {%endblock%}, but you need {%endblock content%}. I think this is causing the problem.
